# Evitar agregar un registro ya establecido en al bd

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo un formulario de ingreso , el botón buscar, trae la información de la BD para modificarla y el botón añadir coloca en nuevo producto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo evitar que el registro que ya esta en la db me la vuelva añadir este seria el metodo para editar

```
        if (this.TxtIdIngreso.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Ha Ingresado El Numero Del Ingreso", "No Ha Ingresado!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            this.TxtCodigo.Select();
            return;
        }
        DialogResult Msg = MessageBox.Show("Desea Actualizar El Ingreso", "Actualizar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (Msg == DialogResult.Yes)
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DtDatos.Rows)
            {
                ED.IdIngreso = TxtIdIngreso.Text;
                ED.Codigo = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);                   
            }
        if (!DalDetalleIngreso.ExisteDetalleIngreso(ED))
        {
            EC.IdIngreso = TxtIdIngreso.Text;
            EC.FechaIngreso = DtIngreso.Value.Year + "/" + DtIngreso.Value.Month + "/" + DtIngreso.Value.Day;
            EC.CCVendedor = Convert.ToString(CbCCVendedor.SelectedValue);
            EC.CedulaProveedor = TxtCedulaProveedor.Text;
            EC.Proveedor = TxtProveedor.Text;
            int Respuesta = NegocioIngreso.NegocioActualizarIngreso(EC);
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DtDatos.Rows)
            {
                ED.IdIngreso = TxtIdIngreso.Text;
                ED.Codigo = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
                ED.Producto = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
                ED.Cantidad = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
                EI.Codigo = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
                EI.Cantidad = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
                int ne = NegocioDetalleIngreso.NegocioAgregarDetalleIngreso(ED);
                int Rta = NegocioInventario.NegocioSumarInventario(EI);
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y que es lo que hace tu metodo: `NegocioIngreso.NegocioActualizarIngreso(EC);`

Comment: yo lo que haria es despues del DialogResult.Yes volveria a realizar otra consulta en al dB para verificar si existe y si eso es verdad entonces procedo a realizar un update de lo contrario hago un simple insert

Comment: ramiro barone se supone que si ya existe lo actualiza

Comment: Manny como seria con un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: NegocioIngreso.NegocioActualizarIngreso(EC); – Ramiro Barone actualiza los datos del ingreso el dataview es detalleingreso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
```  IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM sys.procedures WHERE NAME = 'SumarNuevoInventario')
Begin 
    Print 'El Procedimiento SumarNuevoInventario >>Ya Existe<<'
End ELSE
Begin 
    DECLARE @SumarNuevoInventario varchar(900);
    SET @SumarNuevoInventario = N'Create Procedure SumarNuevoInventario 
    @IdIngreso varchar (50),
    @Codigo varchar (50),
    @CodigoP varchar (50),
    @Cantidad money
    As
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DetalleIngreso WHERE IdIngreso = @IdIngreso and Codigo = @CodigoP) 
    BEGIN
    update Inventario set Cantidad = Inventario.Cantidad + @Cantidad from Inventario, DetalleIngreso where DetalleIngreso.Codigo=@Codigo and Inventario.Codigo=@Codigo END';
    EXEC(@SumarNuevoInventario);
    Print 'Procedimiento SumarNuevoInventario Fue Creada'
End ```
````

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM sys.procedures WHERE NAME = 'AgregarNuevoDetalle')
    Begin 
        Print 'El Procedimiento AgregarNuevoDetalle >>Ya Existe<<'
    End
ELSE
    Begin 
        DECLARE @AgregarNuevoDetalle varchar(555);
        SET @AgregarNuevoDetalle = N'Create Procedure AgregarNuevoDetalle
        @IdIngreso varchar (50),
        @Codigo varchar (50),
        @Producto varchar (50),
        @Cantidad varchar (50)           
        As 
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DetalleIngreso WHERE IdIngreso = @IdIngreso and Codigo = @Codigo) 
        BEGIN
        insert into DetalleIngreso values(
        @IdIngreso,
        @Codigo,
        @Producto,
        @Cantidad)
        END';
        EXEC(@AgregarNuevoDetalle);
        Print 'Procedimiento AgregarNuevoDetalle Fue Creada'
    End
```

Comment: Si bien, el OP marcó tu respuesta como aceptada, es solo código, como sugerencia, considera añadir enunciados

Comment: gracias lo tendre en cuenta

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @SumarNuevoInventario varchar(900);
SET @SumarNuevoInventario = N'Create Procedure SumarNuevoInventario 
@IdIngreso varchar (50),
@Codigo varchar (50),
@CodigoP varchar (50),
@Cantidad money
As
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DetalleIngreso WHERE IdIngreso = @IdIngreso and Codigo = @CodigoP) 
BEGIN
update Inventario set Cantidad = Inventario.Cantidad + @Cantidad from Inventario, DetalleIngreso where DetalleIngreso.Codigo=@Codigo and Inventario.Codigo=@Codigo END';
EXEC(@SumarNuevoInventario);
Print 'Procedimiento SumarNuevoInventario Fue Creada'
```

End ```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM sys.procedures WHERE NAME = 'AgregarNuevoDetalle')
Begin
Print 'El Procedimiento AgregarNuevoDetalle >>Ya Existe<<'
End
ELSE
Begin
DECLARE @AgregarNuevoDetalle varchar(555);
SET @AgregarNuevoDetalle = N'Create Procedure AgregarNuevoDetalle
@IdIngreso varchar (50),
@Codigo varchar (50),
@Producto varchar (50),
@Cantidad varchar (50)
As
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DetalleIngreso WHERE IdIngreso = @IdIngreso and Codigo = @Codigo)
BEGIN
insert into DetalleIngreso values(
@IdIngreso,
@Codigo,
@Producto,
@Cantidad)
END';
EXEC(@AgregarNuevoDetalle);
Print 'Procedimiento AgregarNuevoDetalle Fue Creada'
End
Compartir
Mejora esta respuesta
Seguir

Comment: Has copiado y pegado una respuesta, además tiene problemas de formato y es solo código.